# How can I prove $p \oplus (\lnot p \land q ) \equiv p \lor q$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Having a lot of trouble with the $q$ in $p \oplus q$ being replaced with $(\lnot p \land q)$.

This is for my first unit of Discrete Mathematics, but it's a bit of a curve ball.

I've been picking at it for a few hours, and I think I've managed to reduce it to  $(p \lor q) \land (p \land \lnot q)$ using double negation and reduction laws but I don't know how to prove that it is equal to $p\lor q$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! I want to remind you that it is generally preferred you include context when asking a question here (which can include: where this problem came from, your own attempts, and a *specific* idea as to where you're stuck) - it also lets us help you better! As is, your question is little more than an isolated problem, and thus likely to get a lot of downvotes and closed. Feel free to edit the context into your post though! Here's some useful links: [asking a good question](https://goo.gl/11Cojp) and [a MathJax reference to format your work](https://goo.gl/LtMGrC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A truth table would do the job. One thing you should keep in mind to understand the table is that $ A\oplus B$ is exclusive or. So it would be zero if both $A$ and $B$ have truth value $1$.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline p & q&p \lor q&\neg p&\neg p\land q&p \oplus(\neg p\land q) \\\hline
  1 & 1 &1&0& 0&1\\\hline
  1 & 0&1 &0&0&1\\\hline
  0 & 1& 1& 1&1&1\\\hline
  0 &  0 &0 & 1&0&0 \\\hline
\end{array}$$